# I cant get custom GUIskin to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InfoInput : MonoBehaviour {

    public string charname  = "Name";
    public string usrname   = "User Name";
    public string charrace  = "Race";
    public string charclass = "Class";
    public string charalli  = "LG";
    public string next      = "Next";

    void OnGUI() {
        int x      = 500;
        int y      = 150;
        int w      = 260;
        int h      = 20;
        int buffer = 6;

        charname  = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), charname, 24, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
        usrname   = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), usrname, 24, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
        charrace  = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), charrace, 12, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
        charclass = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), charclass, 20, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
        charalli  = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), charalli, 2, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
       GUI.Button (new Rect (x, y, w, y / 4), next, CustomGUI);  
    }
}
```

and it's not loading from the CustomGUI.guiskin is there something I'm missing here (the manuals didn't tell me how to use it) When I run the script it returns an error saying that my CustomGUI is not a valid reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you've declared your GUI Skin in the code above.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class InfoInput : MonoBehaviour {

    public string charname  = "Name";
    public string usrname   = "User Name";
    public string charrace  = "Race";
    public string charclass = "Class";
    public string charalli  = "LG";
    public string next      = "Next";

    public GUISkin CustomGUI // Add the from the Inspector panel by drag and drop

    void OnGUI() {
        int x      = 500;
        int y      = 150;
        int w      = 260;
        int h      = 20;
        int buffer = 6;

        charname  = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), charname, 24, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
        usrname   = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), usrname, 24, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
        charrace  = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), charrace, 12, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
        charclass = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), charclass, 20, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
        charalli  = GUI.TextField (new Rect (x, y, w, h), charalli, 2, CustomGUI);
        y = y + h + buffer;
       GUI.Button (new Rect (x, y, w, y / 4), next, CustomGUI);  
    }
}
```

If you haven't already, make a `GUISkin` in your Assets Folder by Right-Clicking the Assets tab, going to `Create>GuiSkin`. Then you may add your Skin to it, and drag it to the Inspector panel for use.

Hope it helps.